# How can I code it so the Combobox in Tkinter goes up?

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried to make it so the Tkinter goes up if you click on it but I cant figure out how I can do it. (Default is down)

It would be very nice if someone could help me!

Comment: From what I can see ([Tcl8.6.11/Tk8.6.11 Documentation > Tk Commands > ttk_combobox](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_combobox.html)) the box will only pop down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use style option `postoffset` to change the position and size of the *popdown* via callback of `postcommand` option.

Below is an example:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

def on_popdown_show():
    # get the popup window
    popup = root.tk.eval(f'ttk::combobox::PopdownWindow {combo._w}')
    # get the height of the listbox inside popup window
    popup_height = root.tk.call('winfo', 'reqheight', f'{popup}.f.l')
    # get the height of combobox
    combo_height = combo.winfo_height()
    # set the position of the popup window
    ttk.Style().configure('My.TCombobox', postoffset=(0, -combo_height-popup_height, 0, 0))

combo = ttk.Combobox(root, values=list(range(20)), postcommand=on_popdown_show, style='My.TCombobox')
combo.pack(padx=50, pady=50)

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]